# Sharpest upper bound on $|f(x)|$ using multivariable Taylor approximation, Hessian, or any other method

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, hessian-matrix

(Based on a question in University of Pittsburgh's Preliminary examination: Aug 2016, question 5.)

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function. Let $B=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\colon |x|\leq 1\}$ be the closed unit ball. Suppose $f(o)=Df(o)=o$ and that for an $M\geq 0$, we have
$$
\left \vert \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial_{x_1}^2}(x)\right \vert^2 + 2\left \vert \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_2}}(x)\right \vert^2 +\left \vert \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial_{x_2}^2}(x)\right \vert^2 \leq M^2 , \quad \text{for any $x=(x_1,x_2) \in B$}.
$$

> Give the sharpest bound on $|f(x)|$ for $x \in B$.

By that, I mean something in terms of $M$ and (powers of) $|x|$, or maybe a different norm, like, $|x_1|+|x_2|$.

Please include the details of your argument with clear reference to any lemma/theorem you use.
Your time is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming "$o$" means $0$. By Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder, for $x \in B$,
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x \cdot H(\theta x)x$$
where $\theta \in (0, 1)$ depends on $x$, and $H$ is the hessian of $f$. Note that the bound given in the problem statement is equivalent (by Clairaut's theorem since $f$ is $C^2$) to saying that for $x \in B$,
$$||H(x)||_2^2 \leq M^2.$$
So $||H(x)||_2 \leq M$ for all $x \in B$. Let $x \in B$. Then
\begin{align}
|f(x)| &= \frac{1}{2}|x \cdot H(\theta x)x| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}||x|| \cdot ||H(\theta x)x|| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}||x|| \cdot ||H(\theta x)||_2 \cdot ||x|| \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}M||x||^2. 
\end{align}
The first inequality is by Cauchy Schwarz. The second inequality uses the result that $||AB||_2 \leq ||A||_2 \cdot ||B||_2$, which can be proved using Cauchy Schwarz. I believe the inequalities are sharp in the sense that they are achieved when $H(x) = MI$ on $B$.

Comment: Is it equivalent to? What is meant by $\|\cdot \|_2$, the operator norm?
A deeper question I have is: will the integral remainder as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions yield worse bound?! Why? It's been confusing me so badly!

Comment: $||\cdot||_2$ means the euclidean norm, i.e. square root of sum of squares of the entries.

Comment: The integral remainder yields the same bound. It comes down to bounding $x \cdot (\int_{0}^{1}2(1 - s)H(sx)\,ds)x$ instead of $x \cdot H(\theta x)x$.